# YotubePlayerSupportFragment full screen view in landscape mode

Tags: android, youtube-api

I am trying to show youtube player in fullscreen in landscape mode but it is not working.
I put

```
player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION);
player.setFullscreenControlFlags(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
```

But exception is coming :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set FULLSCREEN_FLAG_FULLSCREEN_WHEN_DEVICE_LANDSCAPE without setting FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION
03-21 16:10:09.892: E/AndroidRuntime(15996):    at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The flags parameter to `setFullscreenControlFlags` is a bitmask, so you should do a bitwise OR of all the flags you want and set them with a single call to `setFullscreenControlFlags` instead of using multiple calls.

Comment: Just FYI, there's also a method `addFullscreenControlFlag` which allows you to add a single flag without clearing the others.